# Can I make display scaling permanent in 19.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, 19.04, scaling

I am using the new fractional scaling feature for high-DPI Monitors in 19.04. It works very well and I enjoy it very much. There is one thing that annoys me a bit. Every time I reboot my computer the scaling factor is reset to 1.0. I have to adjust it in the system settings every time. Is there a way to make the scaling permanent?

OS: Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64
Gnome: 3.32.0
Monitor 1: 3840 x 2160 at 27"
Monitor 2: 1920 x 1080 at 24"
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960

Comment: Same problem in 20.04

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this in 20.04 via gnome settings from Eero Kaan's guide here: https://kaanlabs.com/ubuntu-set-scaling-factor-to-200-percent/.

#### Open Gnome XML config

`sudo vim /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml`

#### Find the line with "displays"

Change the default line in the key name "scaling-factor", which should look somewhat like:

```xml
    <key name="scaling-factor" type="u">
      <default>0</default>
      <summary>Window scaling factor</summary>
      <description> 
        Integer factor used to scale windows by. For use on high-dpi screens.
        0 means pick automatically based on monitor.
      </description>
    </key>
```

Change `<default>0</default>` to `<default>2</default>` and save.

#### Apply your changes

`sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`