# Fractional scaling won't remember settings on restart

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, scaling

I have fractional scaling working at 150% on one display and 100% on the other. When I reboot, these settings are forgotten (as well as the relative position of displays).

How do I persist my settings? This is on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: I would also like to know

Comment: first, how did you achieve different scales on each display?

Comment: It's now a thing. I noticed there is a similar question. I have the same monitor setup as the person who made the post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150008/can-i-make-display-scaling-permanent-in-19-04

Comment: This is what I typed: gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"

Comment: Have you managed to fix this? Edit: nevermind, I'm using Pop OS and I only had to disable the HiDPI daemon.

Comment: No I didn't...However I also installed Pop!_OS ...and it works

Comment: PS: Setting both displays to 150% causes the same thing. I had tried to do exactly the same thing one 150% and one 100%. This bug happened, so I thought maybe using different values caused it (to be fair, I was surprised that I could set so, because, as far as I remember, in the old version, I could not set two different values on X11), and set both to 150%. The display settings (position, scaling, as well as enable state -- because I have three monitors and disabled the third) were lost on the next log on.

Comment: Same thing happening for me. I set primary display to 125% and secondary to 100%. After a restart, the primary is back to 100%, and also the relative position of the secondary is back to the right of primary, even though I dragged it to the left previously.

Comment: I just installed 20.04 and have exactly the same problem: I set settings that are forgotten on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

From: [How to Enable Fractional Scaling in Ubuntu 19.04](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/enable-fractional-scaling-ubuntu-19-04)

> To enable fractional scaling in GNOME 3.32 on Wayland run:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
> ```
>
> To enable fractional scaling in Ubuntu 19.04 on Xorg run:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"
> ```
>
> Once set, you can open `Settings > Devices > Screen Display` to access
>   additional fractional scaling values, including 125% and 150%.

There are many reports of settings not persisting across reboots:

- [Display settings not saved across sessions when using fractional scaling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189339/display-settings-not-saved-across-sessions-when-using-fractional-scaling)
- [Popos 19.04 - X11 fractional scaling not persist after reboot](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/clui9o/popos_1904_x11_fractional_scaling_not_persist/)

If you feel your problem is the same [file a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en).

Using fractional scaling with nvidia cards can be problematic with the nouveau (open source) drivers. You may be better served with the drivers direct from nvidia (closed source).

### Wrong `gsettings`?

It could be the wrong `gsettings` are being run as in this question:

- [Enable fractional scaling for display in ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135303/enable-fractional-scaling-for-display-in-ubuntu-19-04)

```
~$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"
GLib-GIO-Message: 12:22:36.852: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

If that is the case simply use `/usr/bin/gsettings` command.

### Other options

Many use Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity Tweak tool and Font scaling options. For example I have mine set at `1.38` for many years without any problems.

Comment: Description says that fractional scaling is already working. They are asking about persisting the fractional scaling settings.

Comment: Does this answer also apply to ubuntu 22.04. ?

Comment: @MJimitater I haven't tested itt.