# Display settings not saved across sessions when using fractional scaling

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, display, 19.10

I have a pc with:

- Nvidia gtx1080
- two 4k monitors
- Ubuntu 19.10
- nvidia xserver installed

I changed the scaling and order of monitors in Ubuntu Display settings.

However when I reboot or logout/login the display settings reset and i have to set them all over again each time.

How to fix this?

**Update:**

I have narrowed down the bug further.

The settings are not persisted when fractional scaling is used and set.

So with fractional scaling enabled:

If I change the scaling, none of the display settings are persisted across sessions and 100% of settings are reset upon reboot.

If I dont change the scaling (leaving it at 100%), but change other display settings, like the position of monitors, they are indeed persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tackled a similar issue on my system running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 64-bit, GNOME 3.36.8, on X11 with Oracle VM VirtualBox. My display settings, especially fractional scaling, wouldn't stick after a reboot or logout.

Here's the solution that worked for me:

1. Open the terminal and use nano (or your preferred text editor) to edit the .profile file:

   ```
   nano ~/.profile
   ```
2. Add the following lines at the end of the file:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
   gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling', 'scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
   ```
3. Save and exit ^_^