# Display setting reset after reboot Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: display, reboot, settings, 20.04

I am using an external monitor and laptop monitor in extend mode, and every time after reboot 
the monitor to laptop screen position in "Display settings" is reset.

In addition to this I use fractional scaling, 125%, and that is reset as well on reboot.

Newly installed Focal Fossa from ISO.
Using AMD64 version of ubuntu 20.04,
- 1 1080P external monitor connected via hdmi
- laptop monitor with 1080p display
+ Ryzen 50 2500u with Vega Mobile Graphics

I have tried looking at answers available here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/b8jcyl/laptop_display_settings_reset_post_sleepreboot/
[Fractional scaling won't remember settings on restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182358/fractional-scaling-wont-remember-settings-on-restart)

I was able to locate this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1852860
where other users note this problem persists on 20.04 as well.
Wondering if any fixes or other suggestions are known.

Thanks

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182358/fractional-scaling-wont-remember-settings-on-restart

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by following command (I want Scale to be at 200%):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```

Let me know if this has solved your issue!

Comment: When do you execute that command? Can it be done automatically?

Comment: @mr-unperfect, i have tried your solution and it works perfectly. thanks for that but i need 125% scaling so i tried to enter 1.25 but says invalid, any other way?

Answer (score 1):

If you dig into the [bug report you linked](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1852860) it seems clear that the only workaround for this at this moment is turning off fractional scaling or setting fractional scaling to 100%. I recommend that you subscribe to the aforementioned bug report so that you can be notified when a fix becomes available.